# Keyboard is not working in the main screen and in Terminal too

Tags: keyboard

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04lts. From last night, my keyboard is not working except in the lock screen. But it does some command like alt+F4 to close any application. My laptop is HP Pavilion G6.
What can be done?

Comment: If you press the [Super] key, does the keyboard start working?

Comment: matigo, actually I didn't try that.